# marqueeで動いている文字の方向に応じて、その『方向指示ボタン』の矢印を、"点滅"で示すようにするには

Tags: javascript, html

下記のソースコードは、marqueeで動いている文字の方向に応じて、その『方向指示ボタン』の
矢印を"赤"に，反対側の矢印を"白"になるように設定したものです。
この動いている方向の矢印を"赤"で示すのでなく、"点滅"で示すようにするには、どのように
書き換えればいいでしょうか。ご教示ください。

```
<SCRIPT>

 function marLeft(){
   document.getElementById("blinkL").style.color="red";
   document.getElementById("blinkR").style.color="white";
 }
 function marRight(){
   document.getElementById("blinkR").style.color="red";
   document.getElementById("blinkL").style.color="white";
 }


       flg=false;
          function Stop_Start(){
             flg = !flg;
                document.myForm.stopStart.value=flg?"START":"STOP";
   if(flg) {
                document.getElementById("myMarquee").stop();
    } else {
                document.getElementById("myMarquee").start();
    }
 }
</script>


    <marquee id="myMarquee">ＴＴＴＴＴ</marquee>
     <br><br>
    <form id="marFunction" name="myForm" style="text-align:center;">
      <INPUT id="blinkL" type="button" style="color:red; background: black;" onclick="myMarquee.direction='left'; marLeft();" value="←"> 
       ☆
      <input type="button" name="stopStart" value=" STOP " onClick="Stop_Start()">
       ☆
      <INPUT id="blinkR" type="button" style="color:white; background: black;" onclick="myMarquee.direction='right'; marRight();" value="→"> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

要は、質問は「文字を点滅させるにはどうしたらよいか」になると思います。いろいろと方法があり、user9359 さん自身の回答「JavaScriptのタイマーで何とかする」はその一つです。

別解は、

- 画像ボタンにしてアニメーション GIF で点滅させる
- CSS Animation を使う

などあると思います。後者の例です: https://jsfiddle.net/68zfn8t1/

```js
function marLeft() {
  document.getElementById("blinkL").classList.add("BLINK");
  document.getElementById("blinkR").classList.remove("BLINK");
}

function marRight() {
  document.getElementById("blinkR").classList.add("BLINK");
  document.getElementById("blinkL").classList.remove("BLINK");
}

var flg = false;

function Stop_Start() {
  flg = !flg;
  document.myForm.stopStart.value = flg ? "START" : "STOP";
  if (flg) {
    document.getElementById("myMarquee").stop();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myMarquee").start();
  }
}
```

```css
.DIRECTION {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.BLINK {
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite normal;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<marquee id="myMarquee">ＴＴＴＴＴ</marquee>
<br><br>
<form id="marFunction" name="myForm" style="text-align:center;">
  <input id="blinkL" type="button" class="DIRECTION BLINK" onclick="myMarquee.direction='left'; marLeft();" value="←"> ☆
  <input type="button" name="stopStart" value=" STOP " onClick="Stop_Start()"> ☆
  <input id="blinkR" type="button" class="DIRECTION" onclick="myMarquee.direction='right'; marRight();" value="→">
</form>
```

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。animationでもできるのですね。
それに、ソースコードがこんなに簡潔になっているのも驚きました。

Answer (score 0):

専門的には分かりませんが、一応以下のようにすれば機能します。
ただ、"stop"と"start"を切り替える『トグルボタン』ではうまくいきませんので、
普通の『ストップ』ボタンにしました。
また、矢印のボタンを連打すると、その連打した回数だけ反対側の矢印のボタンを
押さないと、正常な状態に戻らない点が難点です。

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>ボタンのラベルを点滅させます</title>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--

   msgA = new Array();
   msgA[0] = "←";
   msgA[1] = "\u0020\u0020\u0020";
   numA = 0;
 var tmr1ID;

     function blinkmsg1(){ //ボタンのラベル（文字）を点滅させます。
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").value ="→";
           clearTimeout(tmr2ID);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").value = msgA[numA];
           numA ^= 1;
           tmr1ID = setTimeout('blinkmsg1()',1000);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").style.color="red";
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").style.color="white";
           myMarquee.direction='left';                 
           document.getElementById("myMarquee").start();
        }

   msgB = new Array();
   msgB[0] = "→";
   msgB[1] = "\u0020\u0020\u0020";
   numB = 0;
 var tmr2ID;

     function blinkmsg2(){ //ボタンのラベル（文字）を点滅させます。
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").value ="←";
           clearTimeout(tmr1ID);
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").value = msgB[numB];
           numB ^= 1;
           tmr2ID = setTimeout('blinkmsg2()',1000);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").style.color="white";
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").style.color="red";
           myMarquee.direction='right';
           document.getElementById("myMarquee").start();
       }

          function stopMarquee(){
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").disabled=false;
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").disabled=false;
           clearTimeout(tmr1ID);
           clearTimeout(tmr2ID);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").value ="←";
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").value ="→";
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").style.color="white";
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").style.color="white";
           document.getElementById("myMarquee").stop();
       }
 //-->
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <marquee id="myMarquee">ttttt</marquee>

   <form name="myForm" style="text-align:center;">
    <input name="blinkA" type="button" id="mybotan1" value="←" onclick="blinkmsg1();"
       style="color:white; font-weight:bold; background:black; text-align : center;">
    <input type="button" name="stop" value=" STOP " onClick="stopMarquee()">
    <input name="blinkB"  type="button" id="mybotan2" value="→" onclick="blinkmsg2();"
       style="color:white; font-weight:bold; background:black; text-align : center;">
   </form>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
　　setTimeout('blinkmsg1()',1000);
 //-->
 </script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: 連打の問題は、『function blinkmsg1(){}』の中に、"document.getElementById("mybotan1").disabled=true;"と"document.getElementById("mybotan2").disabled=false;"を，『function blinkmsg2(){}』の中に "document.getElementById("mybotan1").disabled=false;"と"document.getElementById("mybotan2").disabled=true;" を追加すれば解決できました。

Answer (score 0):

"stop"と"start"を切り替える『トグルボタン』でも、うまく行きました。
なお、スタートさせるには、『方向指示ボタン』で方向を決めて点滅させてから
『START』を押さないと、機能しません。

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>ボタンのラベルを点滅させます</title>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--

   msgA = new Array();
   msgA[0] = "←";
   msgA[1] = "\u0020\u0020\u0020";
   numA = 0;
 var tmr1ID;

     function blinkmsg1(){ //ボタンのラベル（文字）を点滅させます。
           document.getElementById("stop_start").disabled=false;
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").disabled=true;
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").disabled=false;
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").value ="→";
           clearTimeout(tmr2ID);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").value = msgA[numA];
           numA ^= 1;
           tmr1ID = setTimeout('blinkmsg1()',1000);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").style.color="red";
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").style.color="white";
           myMarquee.direction='left';
}
   msgB = new Array();
   msgB[0] = "→";
   msgB[1] = "\u0020\u0020\u0020";
   numB = 0;
 var tmr2ID;

     function blinkmsg2(){ //ボタンのラベル（文字）を点滅させます。
           document.getElementById("stop_start").disabled=false;
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").disabled=false;
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").disabled=true;
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").value ="←";
           clearTimeout(tmr1ID);
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").value = msgB[numB];
           numB ^= 1;
           tmr2ID = setTimeout('blinkmsg2()',1000);
           document.getElementById("mybotan1").style.color="white";
           document.getElementById("mybotan2").style.color="red";
           myMarquee.direction='right';
}

 flg=false;
    function stopMarquee(){
      flg = !flg;
         if(flg){
                 document.getElementById("mybotan1").value ="←";
                 clearTimeout(tmr1ID);
                 document.getElementById("mybotan1").style.color="white";
                 document.getElementById("mybotan2").value ="→";
                 clearTimeout(tmr2ID);
                 document.getElementById("mybotan2").style.color="white";
                 document.getElementById("mybotan1").disabled=false;
                 document.getElementById("mybotan2").disabled=false;
                 document.getElementById("stop_start").disabled=true;
                 document.getElementById("myMarquee").stop();
                 flg=true;
           }else{
                 document.getElementById("stop_start").disabled=false;
                 document.getElementById("myMarquee").start();
                 flg=false;
         }
 　　　　　　document.getElementById("stop_start").value=flg?"START":"STOP";
     }
 //-->
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <marquee id="myMarquee">ttttt</marquee>
<br><br>
   <form name="myForm" style="text-align:center;">
    <input name="blinkA" type="button" id="mybotan1" value="←" onclick="blinkmsg1();"
       style="color:white; font-weight:bold; background:black; text-align : center;">
    <input type="button" id="stop_start" name="" value=" STOP " onClick="stopMarquee()">
    <input name="blinkB"  type="button" id="mybotan2" value="→" onclick="blinkmsg2();"
       style="color:white; font-weight:bold; background:black; text-align : center;">
   </form>

 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
　　setTimeout('blinkmsg1()',1000);
 //-->
 </script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

ここで新たな疑問が生じました。
スタートさせるには、『方向指示ボタン』で方向を決めて"点滅"させてから
『START』を押さないと、機能しませんが、この停止している状態では"点滅"
ではなくて"赤色"にし、スタートさせたら"点滅"するようにしたいのです。
分かる方は、教えていただけませんか。